# Расположение текста в div-е

Tags: css

Задача такая. Нужно, чтобы в самой верхней части был header черного цвета высотой определенного размера. В нем с отступом слева Текст1 и с таким же отступом справа Текст2.
Не понимаю как на этом сайте форматировать текст (на другом, где был, просто нажимаю кнопку, например, пайтон и все). Поэтому прошу прощения.
В шаблоне:

```
<div id="black-bar">
        <div id="black-bar-inside-container">
            <div class="container-left">Текст1</div>
            <div class="container-right">Текст2</div>
        </div>
    </div>
В css файле
#black-bar {
    width: 100%;
    color: white;
    background-color: black;
}

#black-bar-inside-container {
    width: 80%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.container-left {
    float: left;
}

.container-right {
    float: right;
}
```

Подскажите, в чем проблема?

Comment: У родительского блока сейчас нет клиарфикса или оверфло-хидена, поэтому родительский блок не имеет высоты из-за флоатных детей, выбитых флоатом из потока (не участвуют в расчётах родителя).

Comment: Спасибо, так просто ))